# Logstash with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to connect Logstash with Elasticsearch but cannot get it working.

Here is my logstash conf:

```
input {
  stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }

  file {
    type => "syslog-ng"

    # Wildcards work, here :)
    path => [ "/var/log/*.log", "/var/log/messages", "/var/log/syslog" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch{
        type => "all"
        embedded => false
        host => "192.168.0.23"
        port => "9300"
        cluster => "logstash-cluster"
        node_name => "logstash"
        }
}
```

And I only changed these details in my elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: logstash-cluster
node.name: "logstash"
node.master: false
network.bind_host: 192.168.0.23
network.publish_host: 192.168.0.23
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost"]
```

With these configurations I could not make Logstash connect to ES. Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you check if the port number is open?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, I suggest matching your "type" attributes up.
In your input you have 2 different types, and in your output you have a type that doesn't exists in any of your inputs.

For testing, change your output to:

```
output {
stdout { }
elasticsearch{
    type => "stdin-type"
    embedded => false
    host => "192.168.0.23"
    port => "9300"
    cluster => "logstash-cluster"
    node_name => "logstash"
    }
}
```

Then,have you created an index on your ES instance?

From the guides I've used, and my own experience (others may have another way that works) I've always used an index so that when I push something into ES, I can use the ES API and quickly check if the data has gone in or not.

Another suggestion would be to simply run your Logstash forwarder and indexer with debug flags to see what is going on behind the scenes.

Can you connect to your ES instance on 127.0.0.1? Also, try to experiment with the port and host. As a rather new user of the Logstash system, I found that my understanding at the start went against the reality of the setup. Sometimes the host IP isn't what you think it is, as well as the port. If you are willing to check your network and identify listening ports and IPs, then you can sort this out, otherwise do some intelligent trial and error.

I highly recommend this [guide](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/23163863-Installing-Logstash-Central-Server) as a comprehensive starting point. Both points I've mentioned are (in)directly touched upon in the guide. While the guide has a slightly more complex starting point, the ideas and concepts are thorough.

Comment: The key point was the "type" attribute. It has to be matched what given in input must be in output so. That is why Logstash could not be matched any input with output! Thanks you for enlightening me =) By the way the article that you gave very useful, I love it.

Comment: I've encountered many "silly" problems along the way, while setting up a logstash/ES/Kibana system. That guide gave me the best starting point. I can't keep it only for myself! Happy to help.

Comment: Just so you know, tried your link and just got what appears to be the generic support page for shotgun, do you think that guide is still around?

Answer (score 11):

> I could not make Logstash connect to ES

This happened to me when my **logstash and elasticsearch versions were out of sync**

from the docs:

> VERSION NOTE: Your Elasticsearch cluster must be running Elasticsearch
>   1.1.1. If you use any other version of Elasticsearch, you should set `protocol => http` in this plugin.

Setting `protocol => http` explicitly as outlined above fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

As Adam said, the thing was the protocol setting, so only for testing I did:

```
logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost protocol => "http" port => "9200" } }'
```

And that seems to be working on OSX. Issue [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1821).

Comment: This easy config solves my problem. I began with a single node and it works without protocol filed, but I change to two node cluster and I have to add this config.

Comment: Indeed I filed an issue on logstash: https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/1821. Good to know it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 4):

Following is tested on

> elasticsearch:5.4.0

and

> logstash:5.4.0

(I have use docker container on OpenStack)

For Elasticsearch :

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml` should look like as follows -

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

No change in any other files of `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/` is required

Run Elasticsearch using simple command -

```
sudo docker run --name elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
```

For Logstash :

`/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml` should look like as follows -

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline

# http://111.*.*.11:9200 is the IP & Port of Elasticsearch's server 
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://111.*.*.11:9200

# "elastic" is the user name of Elasticsearch's account
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic 

# "changeme" is the password of Elasticsearch's "elastic" user 
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
```

No change in any other files of `/usr/share/logstash/config/` is required

`/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf` should look like as follows -

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/usr/share/logstash/test_i.log"

        }
}


output {

        elasticsearch {
                # http://111.*.*.11:9200 is the IP & Port of Elasticsearch's server
                hosts => ["http://111.*.*.11:9200"]

                # "elastic" is the user name of Elasticsearch's account
                user => "elastic"

                # "changeme" is the password of Elasticsearch's "elastic" user
                password => "changeme"
        }
}
```

Run Logstash using simple command -

```
sudo docker run --name logstash --expose 25826 -p 25826:25826 docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.4.0 --debug
```

NOTE : Need not to do any configuration before running Docker containers. At first run the container using simple commands as mentioned above. Then go to corresponding dir, make the required changes, save it, exit container & restart the container, changes will be reflected.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same error message, and it took me a while to discover in the TRACE log of elasticsearch's discovery process that the ip address logstash was using was incorrect.

I had several ip addresses and logstash used the wrong one. After that, everything went okay.

Answer (score 1):

First,you don't need to create an index in ES.

Because,you **don`t** need to create "index" in elasticsearch;when the logstash assign the index,the index will be created automatically.

By the way,if you did not set the index value,it will be set as default value as "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

[image]

(you can check this in [logstash offcial guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.1/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html))~

Second,you may **not** keep your "elastic type" the same type as your "input type";you can also write your output like this:

```
output {
stdout { }
elasticsearch{
    embedded => false
    host => "192.168.0.23"
    port => "9300"
    index => "a_new_index"
    cluster => "logstash-cluster"
    node_name => "logstash"
    document_type =>"my-own-type"
    }
}
```

With the "**document_type**",you can save your logs into the any type you want~

Finally,if you don`t want to assign the "document_type";it will be set the same with your "input type"

Or even you forget to assign type in "all of the configuration file";the type will be set as default value as **logs**~

OK,enjoy it~

Answer (score 0):

I have a two node cluster of elastisearch, and only one for logstatsh.

This config works for me:

Node elk1:

```
#/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

script.disable_dynamic: true
cluster.name: elk-fibra 
node.name: "elk1"
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["elk1.lab.fibra"]
```

root@elk1:

```
#/etc/logstash/conf.d/30-lumberjack-output.conf
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost protocol => "http" port => "9200" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Node elk2:

```
#/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

script.disable_dynamic: true
cluster.name: elk-fibra
node.name: "elk2"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["elk1.lab.fibra"]
```

Answer (score 0):

input => Logstash

output => ElasticSearch

```
input{
   http {
    port => 5044
    response_headers => {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"
      "Content-Type" => "text/plain"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    }
  }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        user => elastic
        password => ****
  }
```